# Folder permissions

Tags: c#, windows, file-permissions

Why do the following access rule show up as "Special permission" when I browse permissions in the explorer property window? I want it to appear as a normal "modify" access.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigDirectory);
DirectorySecurity security = di.GetAccessControl();
var rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(domainSid, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow);
security.AddAccessRule(rule);
di.SetAccessControl(security);
```

domainSid = SID for domain users.

1. How do I create the rule so it's inherited by all files that are created in that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigDirectory);
DirectorySecurity security = di.GetAccessControl();
var rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(domainSid, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);
security.AddAccessRule(rule);
security.SetAccessRule(rule);
di.SetAccessControl(security);
```

The difference is using a `FileSystemAccessRule` Constructor that allows you to specifiy inheritance and the call to `security.SetAccessRule(rule);`